# MongoDB regex matching trouble

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my MongoDB shell session;

```
> db.foo.save({path: 'a:b'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.foo.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fedc47622e89329d123ee8"), "path" : "a:b" }

> db.foo.save({path: 'a:b:c'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.foo.find({path: /a:[^:]+/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fedc47622e89329d123ee8"), "path" : "a:b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fedc57622e89329d123ee9"), "path" : "a:b:c" }

> db.foo.find({path: /a:[a-z]+/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fedc47622e89329d123ee8"), "path" : "a:b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fedc57622e89329d123ee9"), "path" : "a:b:c" }
```

Clearly the regex `/a:[^:]+/` and `/a:[a-z]+/` shouldn't match string `'a:b:c'`, but looks like Mongo failed on this regex, does anyone know what happened here?

It was submitted to MongoDB Jira, [as a bug ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28951), so is it a bug within MongoDB querying structure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trouble is with the partial matching, since you are not restricting the regex for the whole word, the partial match that exists in `a:b:c` that is `a:b` is resulting in you getting that document.

Use the following regex with `^$` that are anchors to represent beginning and the end of the word;

```
db.foo.find({path: /^a:[^:]+$/})
db.foo.find({path: /^a:[a-z]+$/})
```

This will make the regex apply for the whole string, and ignore the partial matches as explained above. For more on regex anchors, [click here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

So, in summary, *there is no bug, just a misuse of regex.*